# Window.open not focusing in IE when clicked second time or more

Tags: javascript, file, internet-explorer

I am using window.open to open my PDF files. Following is my code.

Reactions of various browsers:

1. In chrome: First time when I click PDF icon, in new window opens the PDF file. I am not closing the opened PDF. Each time when I click on the same PDF icon again it focuses the same file again
2. In firefox: First time when I click , new window opens with PDF file(almost same as chrome), but on consequent clicks of the same file without closing the existing PDF, it opens the same file again and again and focus it.
3. In IE: Here is the major problem. On first click the samething happens as with other browsers but on consequent clicks the opened file is not getting focused and nothing happens at all. 
   Is there anyway to make IE focus on the same PDF that is opened in new window on consequent clicks?
   Also is there anyway to make firefox stop opening same file again and again and just focus on existing like in Chrome?
4. Code sample:

```js
function open_page(url, name, features) {
    var win = window.open(url,
                         (name == null ? 'page' : 'test'),
                         (features == null ? 'menubar=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,width=1024,height=768,resizable=1' : features));

    win.focus();

    if (win == null) {
        alert('Not open');
    } else {
        document.isUnloading = false;
        console.log("#2");
    }
}
```

Tried the following, but still not working in IE. I get tge document focused on 3rd click, 5th and 7th and so on.Not sure why it is working on only alternate clicks.

```
  function open_page(url, name, features) {
        alert("1"+win);
        if (win == null) {
            console.log("#1");
            win = open(url, (name == null ? 'page' : 'test'), (features == null ? 'menubar=1,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,top=500,left=500,width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes' : features));
        }
        else if (isIE()) {
            console.log("#2");
            win.close();
            alert(win);
            win = open(url, (name == null ? 'page' : 'test'), (features == null ? 'menubar=1,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes, top=500,left=500,width=1024,height=768,resizable=yes' : features));

        }
        else {
            console.log("#3");
            window.location.href = url;
            win.focus();
        }
```

Comment: That is the way the `window.open` is handled in each navigators, but you can before calling `win = window.open(url,(name == null ? 'page' : 'test'),(features == null ? 'menubar=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,width=1024,height=768,resizable=1' : features));` check if `win == null ? open the window : win.focus()` remember var win should be declared out side the function.

Comment: I am tried the following, but in IE it works only on alternate clicks. For example, first click opens the PDF in new window. Second click nothing happens. Third click opens again a new window. Fourth time nothing happens. Fifth time again focues same window which was opened third time(window opend on first remains as it is). This pattern continues.  Here is the code in fiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/janae/ed1y4uuz/1/

Comment: Hi.. I am still struck with the above question. The problem is I am not able to close the window with win.close in IE. I have no idea why it is working on alternate clicks. For example second click is nothing is happening. But on third click it again focues on the forst created window. It focues on fifth time , seventh time and so on.. Can anyone help with this

Comment: I have found the solution to the above problem . The problem was the name of the URL.If I change it to "_blank" it works.  var win = window.open(url,
                        '_blank',
                         (features == null ? 'menubar=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,width=1024,height=768,resizable=1' : features));